# Alternative to RectangleShape Component in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, powerpacks, vb-power-pack

I'm looking for a control, like a label, that will have comparable properties to the RectangleShape Component in Visual Studio. And I suppose I should also pose the question: are Visual Basic PowerPacks like the RectangleShape really relevant anymore?

I know it may seem silly, and will not affect the application at runtime, and I may seem like a pampered whiner, but I find the the shape components to be a real nuisance in the layout process. I feel like I'm using an out-dated control. And I particularly find the inability to multi-select regular controls and shape components at the same time most annoying.

Specifically here is what I'm tying to accomplish:

I have been tasked with rewriting an old VB6 program in VB.NET and am constrained to keep the visuals the same as what people are used to.

[image]

In the form above, I need a DiagonalCross pattern behind some text, and I have not found anything that will accomplish the same thing as the RectangleShape component. The FillStyle property only seems to be available in shape components.

For the moment I have resorted to putting all the Shapes and Controls in a Panel, so I can at least move them at the same time, but it is still a little weird to try to adjust the layout within the panel.

I'm hoping there is some way to have the same visual effect in something like a label.
And I suppose I should clarify, I'm looking to find a definitive replacement for the Rectangle Shape component.

I know it may be a silly inquiry, and that the solution may be more difficult than the issue, but I thought I would ask and make sure I'm not missing something easier to replace shapes in the layout process.

I'll greatly appreciate any input. Thanks!

Comment: Many Many controls like the Panel support a background image which could be the crosshatch thing and it is a container control so it naturally will hold other things.

Comment: It would first help if you understand what you were using.  PowerPack shapes are not controls.  There is one `ShapeContainer` control and all shapes are drawn onto that one control.  That's why you can't select multiple controls and multiple shapes.

Comment: @jmcilhinney That's interesting. I wondered about the terminology, and I'll have to look into the ShapeContainer control. Thanks!

Comment: @jmcilhinney Okay, I looked into the ShapeContainer and I see now what you mean, that a shape container is automatically drawn when you place a shape. But an interesting thing is that MSDN describes it as a control. Here's a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.shapecontainer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I just thought I'd share my findings.

Comment: *MSDN describes the RectangleShape and other shapes as controls.

Comment: That's poor writing from whoever wrote that documentation then.  If you check that link you posted, you'll see that the `Control` class is in the inheritance hierarchy for the `ShapeContainer` class but, if you follow the link for the `RectangleShape` class, you'll see that it does not inherit `Control`.  It does inherit `Component`, which is what allows it to be added to the Toolbox, so it is a component but not a control.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ah, I see. Okay, I appreciate the clarification. It's too bad we can't always rely on the MSDN's use of terminology. I'll edit the title and post to to the proper terminology. Thanks!